# Assign Macro To Listbox OnSelectionChange (not OnAction)

Tags: excel, vba

How to assign macro to the listbox on the Excel spreadsheet not OnAction, but on Selection_Change? Listbox is  added via "Developer/Insert/Form Controls. It is NOT the listbox from Userforms.

The problem is if I try to scroll the options in the listbox, then the macro launches, because scrolling is considered as action by Excel. However I'd like macro to run only in case if the user chooses (selects/deselects) some option from the listbox.

I was trying to find some method for the "Shapes" collection. However, did not find any.

Comment: "On value change" so a change event or selection change to a particular range?  More details would be needed, and any efforts you have made to support a macro would be appropriately added to your post [via editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57711230/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your Listindex in a variable and check if it is changed:
(for single select:)

```
Public myIndex As Long

Sub ListBox1_Change()
With ActiveSheet
    If .ListBoxes(1).ListIndex = myIndex Then Exit Sub
    myIndex = .ListBoxes(1).ListIndex
End With
Debug.Print "your macro"
End Sub
```

Make sure on opening of the file myIndex gets populated with the Listindex
and Adjust name of ListBox and (1) accordingly

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, please tick answer as accepted answer, thanks